# The $^1S_0 \rightarrow ^3P_0$ transition in O III

Tags: spectroscopy

Checking out NIST data, I cannot seem to find any data about a $p^2$ valence atom, such as [O III](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html), for the $^1S_0 \rightarrow ^3P_0$ transition. Obviously it isn't a electric or magnetic dipole allowed transition, but what makes this so forbidden that there is no data on it? For reference in the data it should have a wavelength of about $231$nm.

My guess is the $J=0 \rightarrow J=0$, is more strongly forbidden than other transition rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule against $0\rightarrow0$ transitions is the strongest of all selection rules on spectroscopy.  It has a simple explanation.  The photon has $J=1$, and you cannot remove one unit of angular momentum from a system with $J=0$ and still have $J=0$.  Such transitions then typically have to involve more than one photon.  That makes them difficult to observe and their energies difficult to measure.

Comment: Great thanks. I forgot completely about the two photon continuum for Hydrogen, which would have helped my brain fart. Sorry I didn't close this earlier.